# How to add new users into Ajax Chat Script

Tags: ajax, chat

Well, i downloaded the standalone version of this script http://frug.github.io/AJAX-Chat/ and found out that it doesn't have a register page to add new users .so i decided to write it myself .
Users information are stored in chat\lib\data\users.php :

```
<?php
/*
 * @package AJAX_Chat
 * @author Sebastian Tschan
 * @copyright (c) Sebastian Tschan
 * @license Modified MIT License
 * @link https://blueimp.net/ajax/
 */

// List containing the registered chat users:
$users = array();

// Default guest user (don't delete this one):
$users[0] = array();
$users[0]['userRole'] = AJAX_CHAT_GUEST;
$users[0]['userName'] = null;
$users[0]['password'] = null;
$users[0]['channels'] = array(0);

// Sample admin user:
$users[1] = array();
$users[1]['userRole'] = AJAX_CHAT_ADMIN;
$users[1]['userName'] = 'jafar';
$users[1]['password'] = '123456';
$users[1]['channels'] = array(0,1);

// Sample moderator user:
//$users[2] = array();
//$users[2]['userRole'] = AJAX_CHAT_MODERATOR;
//$users[2]['userName'] = 'moderator';
//$users[2]['password'] = 'moderator';
//$users[2]['channels'] = array(0,1);

// Sample registered user:
$users[3] = array();
$users[3]['userRole'] = AJAX_CHAT_USER;
$users[3]['userName'] = '123';
$users[3]['password'] = '123';
$users[3]['channels'] = array(0,1)


?>
```

i added id.txt file in that folder to save the last user id ,then i wrote this code for register page :

```
<html>

<body>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['password']))
{
$name = $_GET['name'];
$pass  = $_GET['password'];

$users =  file_get_contents('.\lib\data\users.php');
$id = file_get_contents('.\lib\data\id.txt');
$users = substr($users,0,strlen($users)-3);

$users = $users . '$users['. $id .'] = array();
$users[' . $id . '][\'userRole\'] = AJAX_CHAT_USER;
$users[' . $id . '][\'userName\'] = \'' . $name . '\';
$users[' . $id . '][\'password\'] = \'' . $pass . '\';
$users[' . $id . '][\'channels\'] = array(0,1);     ' ;



$id=$id+1;
$id=$id+'';
$a = file_put_contents('.\lib\data\users.php',$users.'?>');
$a = $a +file_put_contents('.\lib\data\id.txt',$id);

//if($a!=2)
//echo 'Error !';

}


?>
<center>
<form method=get>
username <input type=text name=name >
<br>
password <input type=password name=password >
<input type=submit>
</form>

</center>
```

but when i tried to open chatroom agian ,i got this error :

`XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: http://localhost/irc/chat/ Line Number 1, Column` 1: ^

what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your are putting 
inside the  tag
the PHP code has to be at the top. Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it is something that will break anything but you didn't close the `<html>` tag or the `<body>` tag. You didn't close any of the input tags either, so you have inputs inside of inputs. Try closing the html and body tags and for the input tags you can replace the `>` with `/>`. If it still doesn't work I will take a further look.

Comment: in html when we open tags it means from that part of code to the end we are using the opened tag expect we close the opening tag, so it won't break anything